# asp.net application authentication problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have an asp web application that is using forms authentication. I am not using asp.net membership provider, I am creating custom authentication. Thus when a user login, I create for him a ticket and a cookie for him and when the user logout I delete them.
I have a problem when the user clicks the close button on top right of the browser. as you know this is a client side event and there is no server side event that run.
My question is:
What should I do when the user clicks the close button in order to remove the ticket and the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

You should use non-persistant cookie. You do this by passing false to the second argument of this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx

Comment: The question mentions that in addition to the cookie, a ticket needs to be removed too. Your solution will not handle that scenario.

Comment: I assume the ticket is in the cookie. This is how forms authentication works. What is more if he is really using forms authentication as he says and has only implemented the backend mechanism (i.e. he is using the FormsAuthentication class) this is only one argument to switch. If he is not using the FormsAuthentication class I bet he's doing it wrong:)

Comment: I suppose @Ghyath Serhal calls "ticket" a flag, a file, a record in a database table or whatever that allows to know somehow a session is active. This "ticket" is deleted/invalidated as soon the session expires. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I don't know what he calls a ticket but he claims to be using forms authentication in ASP.NET. In forms authentication terms "ticket" is the encrypted data needed for authentication stored in the cookie - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443

Of course he may be misusing both "ticket" and "forms authentication" but how do you know that? Surely he may be using "cookie" to refer to a small flat-baked treat but I assume he's not.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook onto "onbeforeunload" DOM event. There are a couple of approaches you can take

1. From the client side set the value of a hidden field and call __doPostBack('fieldid'). In the server side event handler of this field's value chagned event remove the ticket and your authentication token. You can make this an ajax post back. Teh idea is that even if the user closes the browser your web server would have been hit and you will remove the token.
2. In the same event handler fire a web service call to remove the authentication token.

Comment: You have to be careful with IE though, having an onbeforeunload event handler sometimes leads to the code firing the event handler everytime a hyper link is clicked. To get around this you can do something like if ($.browser.msie)
            $('a').live('click', function() {

                var a = 1;

                document.ignoreUnload = document.ignoreUnload || $.inArray(this.id, Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._asyncPostBackControlClientIDs) > -1;


            });

Comment: Did you really suggest doing this just to remove a cookie?

Comment: The idea was to simply trap the browser closign event and fire a server side call for whatever processing is necessary on the server. It could be anything really. So I gave a generic sort of a solution.

Comment: No processing is needed on the server. No processing is needed on the client either. Cookies are automatically deleted when you close the browser unless they are created as persistent. Everything that he has to do is create non-persistent cookies. This is what the "remember me" option on website logins does - switches between non-persistent and persistent cookies.

Comment: Without any clear indication of the meaning attributed to the term "ticket" I gave a solution which is generic enough to capture both scenarios and is "scalable" unlike a shotgun pigeon holed approach to programming which solves the most immediate problem without thinking anything about extensibility and scalability

Comment: Clear indication what "ticket" means - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443 - the Microsoft documentation

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you delete the ticket as soon the user session expires or ends, using session.Abandon() and the session_end event on the service side.

As far I am concerned, I would wait until the timeout closes the session by itself with the ASP.NET session expiration mechanism. Apparently you dont want to rely on it, that's why you need to trap the "windows close" event somehow and send a signal to the server.

[This link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1116238.aspx/1?End%20Session%20When%20Browser%20Closed) might help you to have an example about how to do this.

Comment: Ok. Politness is adding a comment when downvoting, so... Awaiting comment.

Comment: Cookies are automatically deleted when the browser is closed unless created as persistent. No need for any event neither on the client nor on the server side. That's all that persistent cookie means "should it be kept after the browser is closed". If the desired behaviour is to remove the cookie when the browser is closed create it as non-persistent else create a persistent cookie.

Comment: You're right about non persistent cookies. Anyway, @Ghyath Serhal idea is to close the session on the server side, without relying on the timeout mechanism. The problem here is, whatever happens to the cookie to the client side and regardless it is persistent or not, the session on the server side has to be closed when the client windows closes. Closing a session on the server side is important, because resources and stuff might have been allocated and need to be released.

Comment: Please point out where he says that this is his goal or at least where he uses the words "session" or "resources"

Comment: Someone is downvoting answers randomly with contempt and without providing explanations. I personally feel that the person is not really grasping the problem and wants to bulldoze through his/her own solution really. Oh well, all kind of weirdos around. Go on, flag this comment too.

Comment: I am downvoting the answers and I am explaining why. The question states that he wants to remove the ticket and the cookie when using ASP.NET Forms Authentication, doesn't it? Well your answers are wrong or at least answer another question in which case they are also wrong. This is why I am downvoting them. It may be the case that the question is not full or that the user cannot clearly state what he wants but this does not change the fact that the answers are wrong with regard to the current version of the question.

Comment: Well I do understand your concerns about the technical vocabulary. However, it has been understood early and clearly enough by two posters what the question meant by "ticket" which is a generic word in the world of security. No offense meant, it has no more to be taken literally.

Comment: I haven't seen any confirmation what "ticket" means. Also even if you somehow can read the thoughts of Ghyath Serhal this does not mean that people who find this question through search will do too. They will have the right understanding of "ticket" - the one in the documentation.